# Android WebView shows plain text instead of html

Tags: android, android-webview, urlencode

First, I am going to say this is only an issue on Android 2 and older (4 seems to be unaffected and I didn't test 3).

I have a `WebView` that loads html from a string.  The HTML looks like this:

```
<html>  
    <head>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://www.robotsidekick.com/test.css?rev=0' />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can see that css file looks like this:

```
body {
    font-family: "Lucida Console", "Lucida Sans Typewriter", Monaco, "Bitstream Vera Sans Mono", monospace;
}
h1 {
    border-bottom: 3px solid #ccc;
}
```

The `WebView` code looks like this:

```
final WebView webview = new WebView(this);
setContentView(webview);
final String result = "<html><head><link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='http://www.robotsidekick.com/test.css?rev=0' /></head><body><h1>Hello World</h1></body></html>";
webview.loadData(result, "text/html", Encoding.UTF_8.toString());
```

**What Happens**

I see the html code in the `WebView` as if I had set the mime type to plain text.

[image: what happens html as plain text]

**What I'd Expect (and what happens in Android 4.x**

I see the html in the `WebView`

There are a few things that have to be true to show the symptoms I am seeing:

- Android 2.x (I was using 2.3.7 and 2.2)
- The css has to be accessed via a url `href="http://www.robotsidekick.com/test.css?rev=0"` as opposed to `href="test.css"` (however it doesn't matter if it's a real css file `href="http://www.thisisnotarealurl.fake/test.css?rev=0` causes the same problem)
- The css must have a get parameter `?rev=0`, but it doesn't matter what it is

Also wanted to note that the following did not make a difference:

- Using the appropriate `"` instead of `'` in the HTML
- Having the `link` tag close itself or not
- The contents of the css
- Adding a doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>` to the HTML

Comment: i don't understand the issue. Are you saying the CSS doesn't load?

Comment: Sorry, I skipped over what I was seeing and what I was expecting.  Edited to show that.

Comment: to load the CSS, you'll need loadDataWithBaseURL

Comment: I don't care if the css loads or not.  The issue is that the with a fully qualified url, the html is rendered as plain text

Comment: may be you need a doctype ? the strange thing is your example is really similar to what's in the documentation, so it should work

Comment: Oh, yeah I tried a doctype too, didn't make a difference.  I'll add that to the question as a thing I tried.

Comment: Anyone lese struggling with this, I had `"text/html; charset=utf-8"` in the `loadData` method and it caused this issue. You must simply have "text/html".

Comment: Look at my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30420949/webview-shows-source-html-with-loaddatawithbaseurl-not-rendered-view/54322301#54322301

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Changing the `webview.loadData` line to this:

```
webview.loadData(URLEncoder.encode(result).replaceAll("\\+", " "), "text/html", Encoding.UTF_8.toString());
```

Solves this problem.  It seems weird to me that a relative path with an unencoded `?` doesn't cause problems, while a fake url with an unencoded `?` does cause problems.

Also find it odd that the `WebView` changed enough in subsequent versions of Android that we don't have to go encoding our html anymore?  That sounds fishy.