# Android webview doesnt load html file

Tags: android, android-webview

I have a same problem like

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13976193/android-webview-shows-plain-text-instead-of-html)

Problem gets solved with `loadData()`

But it doesnt works with `loadDataWithBaseURL()`

```
v.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/index/",htmlDocument, "text/HTML", "UTF-8",null);
```

Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK i got it...

its simple we just need to change HTML to html i.e.(Capital to small letters)

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, "<body><font size='+2'>My text</font></body>", "text/html", "utf-8", null);
```

Comment: Try solution from Sachin Shelke. I just thought about it too. Perhaps it is the most correct in your case.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use

```
mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/privacy.html");
```